# How can i echo the value of [ 4 -gt 3 ] ,that is a test expression in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell-builtin, bash-functions

How can I echo the value of  [ 5 -gt 4 ]  ,that is a  test expression in bash?

```
[ 5 -gt 4 ] | echo
```

and

```
echo `[ 5 -gt 4 ]`
```

both end up printing a blank line

@Thomas Dickey 's answer works but could some one explain why the above two don`t work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your commands don't work the way you expect them to because the test does not *output* anything to its standard output stream.  It's the standard output stream that gets piped to the next command in a pipeline (your first command), and it's the standard output that replaces a command substitution (your second command).

As an aside, note that even if the left hand side of your first pipeline produced something on its standard output stream, `echo` on the right would not display it.  The `echo` utility does not read from its standard input (but e.g. `cat` does).

---

Any shell command returns an exit status.  This exit status is what e.g. an `if` statement acts upon.  The exit status is never outputted to e.g. the terminal or it would interfere with the actual output of the command or script.

When you use

```
[ 3 -gt 4 ]
```

you call the `[` utility with some arguments.  That utility returns an exit status. It is exactly equivalent to

```
test 3 -gt 4
```

See `man test` and `man [` (or `help test` in the `bash` shell).

The exit status of the most recently executed command is stored in the special variable `$?`.

You may save this in an ordinary variable, or output it to the terminal:

```
[ 3 -gt 4 ]
printf 'Exit status of test was %s\n' "$?"
printf 'Exit status of printf was %s\n' "$?"
```

Note that `printf` *also* produces its own exit status, so if the `printf` call went ok, the value `$?` would be zero after outputting the status of the test.

The code above would likely output

```
Exit status of test was 1
Exit status of printf was 0
```

Note that *the test itself* never outputs anything here.  It just provides an exit status.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concise explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
[ 5 -gt 4 ]
echo $?
```

Comment: But why doesn`t the other method work?

Comment: @strider0160 because `[` doesn't produce any output, it just sets a status/return code.

Comment: why cant that be printed? How does an if statement interpret the test then ? I am a beginner at bash forgive me if these questions are too basic!

Comment: @strider0160 _Output_ means text that would be sent to the terminal (unless redirected or used in some other way). A test does not by itself produce any output. All commands return an _exit status_. This is never printed to the terminal, but what Thomas is showing is how to print the value of the special `$?` variable which holds the exit-status of the most recently executed command (the test in this case).